# How to make upper bound inclusive using SQLAlchemy + Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, range, psycopg2

My column looks like:

```
Class School(db.model):
    year = db.Column(INT4RANGE, nullable=False)
```

And when I commited:

```
y = NumericRange(2020,2021,'[]')
school = School(year=y)
db.session.add(school)
db.session.commit()
```

But when I query the column it shows:

```
[2020,2021)
```

Why is it like that? I need it to include both lower and upper bound for the sake of filtering.

Comment: That seems a bug in SQLAlchemy, `int4range(2020,2021, '[]')` results in `[2020,2022)` in "plain Postgres" https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=632ad97c4a179ceb34dc7a9416841635

Comment: If this is indeed a bug in SQLAlchemy please report it [on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues).

Comment: ```NumericRange``` is actually coming from psycopg2.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Different representation of same thing:
```select int4range(2020,2021, '[]') = '[2020,2021]'::int4range;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Comment: But `2020,2021,'[]'` is something different than `2020,2021,'[)'`. It seems that Python's `NumericRange(2020,2021,'[]')` does something different than `int4range(2020,2021, '[]'`

Comment: No. ```select int4range(2020,2021, '[]');  [2020,2022)
select '[2020,2021]'::int4range;  [2020,2022)``` Pretty sure what @roocs is showing is some of the output of the query, not the value of `y` passed into the query.

Comment: Is ```[2020,2021)``` in the output from the query. If so then it is appropriate as the canonical form for ```int4range``` is ```[)```. [Bounds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY) "The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, [). "

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SQLAlchemy installed but here is what I see:

```
create table integer_range(range_field int4range);
insert into integer_range values (int4range(2020, 2021, '[]'));
insert into integer_range values (int4range(2020, 2021, '[)'));
insert into integer_range values (int4range(2019, 2020, '[)'));
```

In Python:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import NumericRange
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=aklaver host=localhost port=5442") 
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.mogrify("select * from integer_range where range_field = %s", (NumericRange(2020,2021,'[]'),))                                                                                                                      
b"select * from integer_range where range_field = '[2020,2021]'"
cur.execute("select * from integer_range where range_field = %s", (NumericRange(2020,2021,'[]'),)) 
rs = cur.fetchall() 
rs[0]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
(NumericRange(2020, 2022, '[)'),)
```

So it works as far as the psycopg2 ene.